# Error loading tensorflow - Could not find "cudart64_80.dll"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to import tensorflow (with GPU) and keep getting the following error:

> ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_80.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable

**Setup:**

- NVIDIA GTX 1080
- CUDA Development Tool v8.0
- cuDNN 6.0
- tensorflow-gpu 1.4

**Environment variables:**

- CUDA_HOME: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0
- CUDA_PATH: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0
- CUDA_PATH_V8.0: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0

I have also added the following to the %PATH% variable:

- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\libnvvp
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64

What am I missing? Why it can't find cudart64_80.dll despite its location is explicitly specified in %PATH%?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In certain cases you may need to restart the computer to propagate all the changes.

If you are using intellij or pycharm, make sure to restart that as it may not take the correct path environment variables otherwise.

Comment: That's what I figured at the end. Restarting IntelliJ was not enough to reflect changes in the system environment variables

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but with the version 9.1 which I had on my machine.

The one which was missing  'cudart64_90.dll', whereas there was  'cudart64_91.dll'. So I did a 'downgrade' from CUDA 9.1 to 9.0 and it solved my problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: agreed, I made the same mistake, and installed 9.2, so I had to downgrade to 9.0 and install the cuDNN for 9.0

Answer (score 0):

I just changed cudart64_90 to cudart64_80. It worked